# Deadlock in Delphi Application

Tags: multithreading, delphi, deadlock, udpclient

Can the bellow scenario cause deadlock in any way? Basically i define and create a TIdUDPClient instance in a background thread then i send the identifier of this instance (as a method parameter) to a class instance ('mst') that was created in the main thread ( mst.GetSlvStatus( j, FIdUDPclient) ). In 'mst.GetSlvStatus' i do not poke the UI.

```
  TSlvPolling = class(tThread)
  private
    FIdUDPclient : TIdUDPClient;
    FFreq: integer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    SimpleEvent: TSimpleEvent;
    constructor Create( afreq: integer; aPollMode: integer );
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure StatePoll;
  end;



procedure TSlvPolling.StatePoll;
var
...
begin
  while not terminated do begin
  end;    
    while msts.Count <> 0 do begin
      for i := 0 to mstscount - 1 do
      begin
        mst := msts[i]; 
        if mst <> nil then 
        begin
          try   
            ...  
            for j := 0 to mst.cnt-1 do begin
              if terminated then exit else begin  
                mst.GetSlvStatus( j, FIdUDPclient ); //'mst' was created in the main thread
                sleep(500); 
              end;
            end;
            if not terminated then 
              PostMessage(frmDTree.handle, WM_SLVPOLL_CHANGE, integer(mst), 0); 
          end;
          except  
          end;
        end else 
          continue;
      end;
      if (SimpleEvent.WaitFor( FFreq ) <> wrTimeOut) then exit;    
      if terminated then 
        exit;
    end;    
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you call `StatePoll` from the main thread?

Comment: I call it from TSlvPolling.Execute

Comment: Without knowing what `mst` and `msts` are, and what `mst.GetSlvStatus()` does, there is no way to answer whether that code can deadlock. However, note that using `frmDTree.handle` in the thread's `PostMessage()` call is NOT safe, because the `TWinControl.Handle` property getter is NOT thread-safe, and that CAN cause issues if the `Handle` is ever recreated at runtime. A safer option is to post to a window that is guaranteed never to recreate - either the `Application.Handle` window (use `TApplication(Events).OnMessage` to receive the posted message), or a dedicated window via `AllocateHWnd()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i defined a dedicated window in the form's constructor (whnd := AllocateHWnd(SlvPollingChangeNode);) and now the application does not even start.
'SlvPollingChangeNode' is a public method of the same form.

Comment: @kidbro please [edit] your question to show that code. And you didn't answer my earlier question about what the various portions of your code are and what they do. So it is still not possible to determine whether your code can deadlock or not.